# Axios POST call doesn't work with JWT token, while GET call works

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, jwt

I'm trying to build REST API in Django which I connect with Vue.js on the front end by using the axios library with using the JWT token authentication.

However when I make POST Django says Unauthorized, while when I use GET everything seems to work correctly.

Both POST and GET are defined as part of the same class and I use permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) to check for permissions.

Backend class:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Generic API views
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, mixins
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from api.models import Movie
from api.models import WatchList

from api.serializers import WatchListSerializer
from api.add_movie import add_movie


class WatchListAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    
    """
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        "Returns all the movies in personal watch list"
        current_user = request.user
        current_watchlist = WatchList.objects.filter(user=current_user).prefetch_related('movie')

        serializer = WatchListSerializer(current_watchlist, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        current_user = request.user
        new_movie_id = request.data['movie_id']

        # In case we don't have current movie in our database
        add_movie(new_movie_id) 

        current_movie = Movie.objects.get(movie_id=new_movie_id)

        new_watchlist_element = WatchList(
            user=current_user,
            movie=current_movie
        )

        if(WatchList.objects.filter(user=current_user, movie=current_movie).count() != 0):
            return Response({"error": "that movie is already present in the watchlist"})
        
        new_watchlist_element.save()
        return Response({"message": "added new movie"})
```

Front end call which work:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/watchlist/', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + currentToken.access
          }
        }).then(
          data => {
            this.watchList = [];
            for(let i=0;i<data.data.length;i++) {
              this.watchList.push({
                movieTitle: data.data[i]['movie']['movie_name'],
                shortSummary: data.data[i]['movie']['overview'],
                yearProduction: data.data[i]['movie']['production_year'],
                moviePoster: data.data[i]['movie']['poster_path'],
                rating: 5,
              });
            }
          }
        );
```

Front end call which doesn't work:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/watchlist/', {
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + currentToken.access
            },
            movie_id: this.movieSearchQueue[i]['movieId'],
          }).then(data=>console.log(data));
```

Comment: You need to show us some code

Comment: I have just added code, the axios.get works while axios.post doesn't

Comment: Can I see your REST_FRAMEWORK settings, please?

Comment: I have configured the CORS_HEADERS there, I added those two things in the axios post call and it seems to work now: 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: Good to hear, then perhaps, you may answer you question with the working solution and accept it so other people may find it easily

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I should've added more details into the Axios post call, as it started working after I added those two things into the headers of the post call:

```
'Accept' : 'application/json', 
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```